# given prefix, how to find most frequently words effiecitly

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is a interview question extended from this one: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-k-most-frequent-words-from-a-file/

But this question required on more thing: GIVEN PREFIX

For example, given "Bl" return most frequently words such as "bloom, blame, bloomberg" etc.

SO using TRIE is a must. But then, how to efficitnly construct heap? It's not right or pratical to construct heap for each prefix at run time. what could be a good solution.

[suppose this TRIE or data structure is static, pre-build]

thanks!

Comment: Are you asking what is the best data structure to hold the words, if you're going to be querying for prefixes? You probably want a DAWG: Directed Acyclic Word Graph.

Comment: @jim wow, this is really a complex data structure. thanks. But i felt like, in the interview, he still wanted me to use trie but with some improvement/modification. not sure.

Comment: The DAWG *is* "a trie with some improvement/modification."

Answer (score 0):

Keep a trie for all the words appearing in the file and their counts. So now if it asked to return all the words with the prefix "BI", then you can do it efficiently using the trie formed. But since you are interested in giving the most frequently occuring words with the prefix "BI", you can now use a min-heap to give the answer efficiently just like it has been done in the post you have linked to.

Also note that since the space usage of a trie can grow very large, you can suggest the interviewer to use a [Ternary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree) instead of a trie.

Comment: 1. Do you mean i construct heap for each prefix?then how many heap I end up with? Too manh.
2. Do you say I construct heap after user query it?
thanks!

Comment: How can a trie occupy exponential space? The number of nodes in a trie must be less than the total number of characters in all strings, which is also the space requirement for storing all the strings uncompressed. You can compress the trie by eliminating nodes with only one descendant, in which case you reduce the upper limit to the number of strings (but you then have to store the character sequences, so the space complexity is still in the same `O()`). It is true that a TST is likely to be smaller, at the cost of increased search time. There are other space reduction techniques as well.

Comment: The number of nodes will be lesser than the total no. of chars but the no. of pointers will be much larger. And each such pointer occupies space. And surely there are other space reduction techniques but I think talking about TST should be a good starting point.

Comment: @NoName I mean construct the heap after the user queries it. But keep on maintaining the trie as the strings come in. So whenever a query arrives, you just have to look at the strings that have the asked string as a prefix.

Comment: @NikunjBanka: If your trie node is an array, the number of pointers will be larger but only linearly, not exponentially, since there are O(1) pointers per node. "Exponentially larger" is not a synonym of "much larger".

Comment: @NikunjBanka this does not sounds too efficient. we will end up with A LOT of heaps